# Express Sequelize and Passport.js authentication strategy not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, passport.js, sequelize.js

I have the following authentication strategy for Express and Sequelize using passport.js:

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../../models').User;

module.exports = function (passport) {

    passport.use('register', new LocalStrategy({
            passReqToCallback: true,
            usernameField: 'email'
        }, function (req, email, password, done) {

            //var findOrCreateUser = function () {
            // find a user in Mongo with provided username
            User.findOrCreate({where: {email: email}}).spread(
                function (user, created) {
                    // In case of any error, return using the done method
                    //if (err) {
                    //    console.log('Error in SignUp: ' + err);
                    //    return done(err);
                    //}

                    if (email !== req.param('email-confirm')) {
                        console.log('Registration: Email address do not match');
                        return done(null, false, {message: 'Email addresses do not match'});
                    }

                    // already exists
                    if (user) {
                        console.log('User ' + email + ' is already registered.');
                        return done(null, false, {'message': 'The email ' + email + ' is already registered.'});
                    } else {


                        // if there is no user with that email
                        // create the user
                        var newUser = new User();

                        // set the user's local credentials
                        newUser.email = email;
                        newUser.password = password;

                        // save the user
                        newUser.save(function (err) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log('Error in Saving user: ' + err);
                                throw err;
                            }
                            console.log('New user registration', newUser);
                            return done(null, newUser);
                        });
                    }
                });
            //};
            //// Delay the execution of findOrCreateUser and execute the method
            //// in the next tick of the event loop
            //process.nextTick(findOrCreateUser);
        })
    );

};
```

The problem is that when I execute the code it fails to insert into the db with the following error:

```
Executing (fa4929e4-6b35-40ce-9e02-daf80af507e1): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (fa4929e4-6b35-40ce-9e02-daf80af507e1): SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
Executing (fa4929e4-6b35-40ce-9e02-daf80af507e1): SET autocommit = 1;
Executing (fa4929e4-6b35-40ce-9e02-daf80af507e1): SELECT "id", "email", "password", "lastLogin", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt" FROM "Users" AS "User" WHERE ("User"."deletedAt" IS NULL AND "User"."email" = 'user@email.com') LIMIT 1;
Executing (fa4929e4-6b35-40ce-9e02-daf80af507e1): COMMIT;
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Object [object SequelizeInstance:User] has no method 'isModified'
    at sequelize.define.instanceMethods.save (/home/otis/Developer/Project/models/users.js:24:26)
    at Model.create (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1735:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1837:17)
    at Object.tryCatcher (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:503:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:577:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:128:12)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
    at Async.drainQueues (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

I know it is during the user creation because if I get it to error with the same email address that all works. But if it starts to create a user it errors out, and the web page stalls.

Update: If I run it with just `.find`:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "email", "password", "lastLogin", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt" FROM "Users" AS "User" WHERE ("User"."deletedAt" IS NULL AND "User"."email" = 'user@email.com') LIMIT 1;
Unhandled rejection TypeError: expecting an array, a promise or a thenable

    See http://goo.gl/s8MMhc

    at PromiseArray.init [as _init] (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise_array.js:42:27)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:575:21)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:693:14)
    at Async._drainQueue (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:123:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
    at Async.drainQueues (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Update: removed `.spread`:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "email", "password", "lastLogin", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt" FROM "Users" AS "User" WHERE ("User"."deletedAt" IS NULL AND "User"."email" = 'user@email.com') LIMIT 1;
express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead middlewares/authentication/registration-strategy.js:21:39
Unhandled rejection TypeError: object is not a function
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/otis/Developer/Project/middlewares/authentication/registration-strategy.js:35:39)
    at tryCatcher (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:503:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:577:18)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:693:14)
    at Async._drainQueue (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:123:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
    at Async.drainQueues (/home/otis/Developer/Project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Comment: what happens if you replace `findOrCreate` with just `find` ? since you're creating user later, there is no need to use it.

Comment: remove `spread`: `findOne({email: email}).then(function(user){ ... })`

Comment: sorry what do you mean?

Comment: `spread` expects array of values, or promises. But `findOne/find` returns single value. So replace `User.findOne().spread()` with `User.findOne({email: email}).then(function(user){ ... })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequelize model is not a constructor (i.e. you can't call `new`).

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/

Use it as a factory, either by calling `build`, which returns a new, unsaved instance, or calling `create` which returns a promise that resolves with a saved instance